# How to Cluster issue letsencrypt to hover.com using Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

Hello I am using Helm Chart to issue cert-manager CLusterIssuer

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: {{ .Values.email }}
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer-key
    solvers:
    - http01:
       ingress:
         class: nginx
```

however I am not using any Cloud DNS, but using Hover.com as my domain delegation, how can I solve the certificate from hover?

Answer (score 0):

http01 does not require any interaction with the DNS provider from cert-manager. That is only needed for dns01 validations.